# Git pull merge fetch

Tags: git, merge, fetch, pull

I'm trying to solve a problem with Git. I'm using TortoiseGit.

Basically I checked out the master-branch and without making any changes and now I want to do an update of my local repo.

As I understand there a few commands for this:

**Fetch**: Downloads info from the remote branch

**Merge**: Merges said info into the local branch

**Pull**: Combines above operations

However, there a few things that I see that I don't understand:

- When I do check for modifications, it shows me that I have modified a lot of files (which I didn't). I somehow think these changes are related to changes in the remote branch
- When I do a fetch it fetches the remote info correctly, if I then do a merge it says "Already up to date", however, if I do a pull (which supposedly combines both) I get an error saying that my local modifications would be overwritten by the merge. This surprises me, since I didn't make any local modifications. This is probably related to the previous point, but I fail to see how.

Am I misunderstanding the basics of Git, or could anyone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: What is weird to me is that fact that I haven't touched any files. I did however execute fetch once. Currently I have the latest version of the code, but only after I did a revert and then a pull. How did said changes land in my local repo?

Comment: Could it be that the line endings were changed from unix to windows or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

There could be many things that can be considered a change. First of all the equivalent of `git pull` is actually.

```
git fetch
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

Now, after you do this, you probably want to do `git diff FETCH_HEAD` to see what is Git considering as a difference. You might want to replace FETCH_HEAD to something more user friendly, like `origin/master`.

It could be line-endings, or it could be simply the modification time of the files, either way, if you want to get rid of your "modifications", you can do `git reset --hard` which would reset all the work tree files to what they were in HEAD, and presumably you can do the pull now.

Alternatively, you can reset directly to the latest `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` (or e.g. origin/master).